# Не работает подсветка синтаксиса в jb project rider при работе с Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, syntax, rider, highlighting

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Script : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Light lighting;
    void Start()
    {
        lightting = GetComponent<Light>();
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Не работает подсветка синтаксиса. Такое впечатление, что `Project Rider` не может определить, в какой среде работает. В Unity самом поставил, чтобы [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) скрипты открывал через Project Rider. То есть, при наборе методов он должен автоматически подсвечивать все доступные. А он только некоторые слова синем выделил и всё. Анализ кода включён.

Kак исправить?

Comment: Вы собственно вопрос решили?

Comment: .........Да.........

Comment: Если вы решили вопрос, то нужно отметить свой ответ галочкой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Там немного странно получилось. У меня скрипты автоматически через Project Rider запускались, вот я и не стал выставлять, каким Ide открывать их в unity. Когда с проблемой столкнулся, решил выставить. Ничего не изменилось, а надо было после этого перезапустить IDE, но я скрипт удалил и новый создал, чтобы наверняка.